# Getting back number of rows in table returns -1

Tags: c#, ado.net

Hi I am tryng to count the number of rows in a table but I alwyas get back -1.Here is my code:

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
      connection.Open();
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CountBooks", connection);
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      numberOfBooks = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Books
```

How can I get the correct result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery.